# xmlhttp.status = 500 after 2 previous calls

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am creating a multiple tear drop down selection, as part of a form.

The idea is, 6 choice levels will ultimately result in a value to insert into a form field.

javascript in header of form

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getInfo(str) 
    {
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("catTitle").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("catTitle").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","cat_title.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

I created 1 script for each selection -- i am new to javascript/jquery and know so little, i wasn't seeing a simplified way, yet, to use one script and call multiple times -- as a result, I call getInfo() for the first, getInfo2() for the second, getInfo3() for the third and so on.

in the body of the document, i begin a form.  inside the form, i have my selection boxes -- and want to use onchange='function()' to call for each value, and will result in inserting the value into the

here are the selections as they are now.

```
Select Category : <br>
                            <select  name="level1" id="level1" onchange="getInfo(this.value)">
                                <option></option>
                                <?
                                $sql="SELECT * FROM Ebay_Category WHERE Level='1' ORDER BY Category";
                                $results=mysql_query($sql);
                                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results)){
                                    if($row['CategoryID']!=$lastrowid){
                                    echo "<option value='".$row['CategoryID']."' >".$row['Category']."</option>";
                                    $lastrowid=$row['CategoryID'];
                                    }
                                }

                                ?>      

                                </select>
                                <br>

                                <span id="catTitle"></span><br>
                                <span id="catTitle2"></span><br>
                                <span id="catTitle3"></span><br>
                                <br><br>
```

here is the code from my first cat_title.php file, each one changes the id on the next selection box created; (i also take advantage of every call to track the session time, so i can have it time out after 10 minutes. -- I also make a habit of collecting the users name, so i can easily add to a log file later, although i cannot see adding a log file to a simple selection - I just wanted to explain in case this is helping me reach a limit of calls I'm not aware of)

```
    <?php
    include "signup/include/session.php";
include "signup/include/z_db.php";// database connection details stored here
$gap=10; // change this to change the time in minutes, This is the time for which active users are collected. 
$tm=date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime (date("H"),date("i")-$gap,date("s"),date("m"),date("d"),date("Y")));
$ListerID=$_SESSION['userid'];
mysql_connect("$servername", "$dbusername", "$dbpassword")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$dbname")or die("cannot select DB");
$userInfo=(mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM plus_signup WHERE userid='$ListerID'")));
$UserLevel=$userInfo['users_level'];
//check to see if leaf, if yes - echo result only


$vx=$_GET["q"];
$LeafCheckSQL="SELECT * FROM Ebay_Category WHERE ParentID='".$vx."' ORDER BY Category";
$result=mysql_query($LeafCheckSQL);

echo "<select id=\"lev2\" onchange=\"getInfo2(this.value)\">";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option value='".$row['CategoryID']."'>".$row['Category']."</option>";
}
    echo "</select>";
//}
?>
```

works to build a 2nd drop down, which once selected, works to build a 3rd drop down.

I've added alert('messages') to help me track the problem, and in the 3rd drop down, when i call the getInfo(str) call -- it steps through the entire process, but the xmlhttp.readyState that needs to be 4, and xmlhttp.status that needs to be 200, first show up as 2:500 respectively, and then on what seems to be a retry to the onreadystatechange, it goes to 4:500 --

Here is another strange thing, if it was a limit - why can I use the form selection 1 2 just fine, with 4:200 with every call, even after the 3rd fails.  I am so lost with this.

I'm adding as much information as possible, after this project I will dedicate some serious study to learning jquery, as it seems to be so extremely useful.

However, I would LOVE it if someone would treat me like the absolute beginner I feel like, and give me a walk through understanding of what I've done wrong, and what I could do to fix this please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: thats not good :(  is there a way to make the same calls, but protect against an attack?

Comment: don't build your sql by combining user input and raw sql.

Comment: you mean, the get is opening the whole?

Comment: that and the session might be insecure.

Comment: ok, thank you :)  I have tons of these, I won't waste your time anymore - only thank you for the advice, and throw myself headlong in to research mode.  I'm freaking out a little by the way.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is simple -- be more thorough next time.

I found that my newly created cat_title.php files were uploaded to the server, with too low permission -- i couldn't read them from the browser.

fixed with a simple right click in filezilla, and changed permissions.

Thank you to anyone who took the time to try to solve this for me, and I am sorry for the trouble.